# Create a health bar

Tags: c#, debugging, textures, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a working health bar, and I have tried methods like

1. Creating GUI.Box() that contains the health bar texture that I have created, but this makes the health bar resize to scale like this: 
   [image: Distorted Health Bar]
2. Resizing the texture itself **without** the GUI.Box(), using the **Texture2D.Resize()** Method, but when I used the **Texture2D.Resize()** method, my texture turned **black**. It looks like this:

[image: Black Health Bar]

My code looks like this. It was edited so that the irrelevant parts were deleted for ease of reading.

[image: Code]

Why does my health bar turn black when I resize it? Are there any ways I can prevent this from happening? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Remove** all API that starts with **GUI**.... then remove your `On GUI(){....}` function.

**SLIDER:**

Go to **GameObject->UI->Slider.**

Delete **Handle Slide Area** from the slider.

Then to control the health bar from script:

First, Include `using UnityEngine.UI;`

```
public Slider healthBar;

//Initialize health bar
void Start()
{
healthBar.interactable = false;
healthBar.minValue = 0;
healthBar.maxValue = 100;
healthBar.value = 100;
}
```

You can then change your health bar with `healthBar.value`.

**FOR THE BAG IMAGE:**

Go to **GameObject-UI->Image**. Stop using the old GUI.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui

Comment: Is using UI more preferred than GUI, and are there any reason in particular for my texture turning black?  @Programmer

Comment: @AaronGe Is driving a car from Japan to North Korea preferred than buying a plane ticket and flying to North Korea? GUI was used when Unity did not have any other UI. After 4.6 release, Unity made a new UI and the old GUI is deprecated and will be removed soon.GUI  is slow and has more draw calls than UI. I wouldn't rule out bug as the reason your image is black.